# «Показывая, что всё в порядке(,) и…» Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

**Она махнула рукой, показывая, что всё в порядке / всё нормально / всё хорошо(,) и села рядом.**
Есть ли смысл ставить перед «и» запятую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна не только перед "и", но и на месте слешей — между однородными членами.

*Она махнула рукой, **показывая, что всё в порядке, всё нормально, всё хорошо,** и села рядом.*

Главное предложение с однородными сказуемыми — ***Она махнула*** рукой **и села** рядом.
Деепричастный оборот находится внутри главного предложения, поэтому запятая перед "и" необходима — она закрывает придаточное.

Вот похожее предложение.
*Она махнула рукой, показывая, что не стоит и говорить о такой ерунде, и скрипнула креслом.*

P. S. Запятая перед "и" не нужна вот в этом предложении.
*Она махнула рукой, показывая, что всё в порядке и можно присоединяться.*
(...показывая, что всё в порядке и [что] можно присоединяться.)

P. P. S. Не сразу поняла, что Вы имели в виду только одно из перечисленного, — на требующуюся запятую перед "и" это не влияет.
*Она махнула рукой, показывая, что всё хорошо, и села рядом.*

Comment: Спасибо огромное! :)